# How to collect a map from the stream that returns the map in java

Tags: java, java-8

I know there are various examples of how to collect a map from another map. My use case is a little bit different here.
I want to get the `Map<String, String>` at line 10, but could not do it. I am new to the streams in java. Appreciate any help

MyMain.java

```
public void uploadMyFiles( MultipartFile file) {
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

List<String> s3Paths;

CompletableFuture<Map<String, String>> downloadTasks = s3Paths
        .stream()
        .flatMap(s3Path -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> uploadMyFile(file, s3Path), executor))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s3Path, "")); //at line 10
}
```

uploadMyFile method:

```
private Map<String,String> uploadMyFile(MultipartFile file, String path){
    
 return null;
}
```

Comment: It seems you should use `.map(s3Path -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...)).collect(Collectors.toList());` instead of `... flatMap(...).collect(Collectors.toMap(s3Path, ""));`

Comment: you expected return type is list not map,why?

Comment: Fix your indenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void uploadMyFiles(MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    List<String> s3Paths = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A","B"));

     Map<String, String> downloadTasks =
    s3Paths.stream()
        .map(
            s3Path -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> uploadMyFile(file, s3Path), executor)) //Returns a Stream of CompletableFuture<Map<String,String>
        .map(getCompletableFutureMapFunction()) //Returns a Map<String,String>, refer to the function where we are getting the computed result from CompletableFuture
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()) // FlatMap to convert Map<Map<String,String> to Map<String,String>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)); //Collect as Map<String,String>, if required, you can add a merger function here
 }


  private Function<CompletableFuture<Map<String, String>>, Map<String, String>> getCompletableFutureMapFunction() {
    return future -> {
      try {
        return future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    };
  }

  private Map<String,String> uploadMyFile(MultipartFile file, String path){
    return null;
  }
```

Comments are in-line :) I know exception handling is not done in a good way, This would surely give you a start though!

Comment: Thank you, sir, @mohamed-anees-a for your complete example. It works like a charm!

Comment: Sorry for another follow-up on this, I got a requirement to pass an array of the multipart file as input and I need to upload them parallelly. since MultipartFile is an interface, I can't iterate using streams, is there a way I can achieve this in my example?

Comment: Please ask a different question :) and, show us what you’ve tried for that

Comment: Thx. here is my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832967/how-to-iterate-over-multipartfile-array-using-java-lamda-and-streams